# What are promising replacements for throwaway electronics?

Tags: electronics

What are promising replacements for throwaway electronics?

Computers, mobile phones, etc. certainly seem useful, but they have a limited lifetime, and the recycling of components seems a difficult/impossible endeavor.

What options are there?

Comment: It doesn't help when operating systems such as Windows 11 are introduced that require computers with specific hardware requirements for supposedly security reasons. Anyone who has an old computer that functions perfectly well & they are happy with their situation then has the dilemma of either having to dispose of the old computer & buy a new one to use Windows 11 or abandoning Microsoft operating systems & install GNU/Linux on the perfectly functioning computer they have been using for many years.

Comment: @Fred Yes, which is why I've thought that extending support backwards might be ecologically more sound even when several vendors seem to not want to do it due to so few users. But I am not sure whether "so few users" is the chicken or the egg. It is also possible that software vendors rely on business techniques that make upgrades unavoidable. It sounds reasonable that prolonging the lifetime of products might not be profitable.

Comment: I think there are other factors at play as well. We are being increasing regarded as a product for advertisers by "tech companies". They want to monitor us for various reasons, some of them business related. With older platforms they can't do that. By making the new systems incompatible with the old they are trying to force users into their preferred channel so it's easier for them to maintain a long term income source. It's a variation of the concept of design obsolesce, or consumer engineering, as the term was in the 1930s. To complement this, we are also being forced into using online ...

Comment: ... storage & away from storing things on local hard drives: long term storage devices that we own. We also being forced into a situation where a computing device is only useful when constantly connected to the world wide web - software such as Office 365 (ex Microsoft Office)  that can only be used via a continual online link & no long installed on local computers. There are advantages regarding updating such software by doing this, but there are also disadvantages as well.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is to use what you have for as long as you possibly can. My laptop is more than five years old, my "new" phone is two and replaced a five+ year old phone.

There are products like and FairPhone, PinePhone in the smartphone area that try to be less bad and explicitly have longer lasting and more repairable as goals. Arguably that has helped push the other manufacturers to increase their product lifetimes too.

With laptops there's a similar push for sustainability, with PineBook again making one. There's also a lot of corporate interest, with "TCO laptop" being your keyword there. But for many people a second hand or refurbished laptop is a better choice.

Computers more generally work in a similar way. Buy what you need, ideally second hand, and fix what you can when bits break.

With ewaste, right now there are no really good recycling options. It's a toss-up between selling things for parts, stockpiling them in a cupboard somewhere, or sending them in to whatever ewaste recycling system(s) are available where you are.

For me local supermarkets and office supply places will take batteries and a few other parts, so I've been pulling those out of dead items and dropping them there (because [battery recycling in Australia](https://envirostream.com.au/) actually happens). There are commercial ewaste recyclers here, and luckily my workplace pays one of them to collect our stuff every year and my employer lets us all contribute to the pile (we can also reuse stuff out of the pile if we want to).

Answer (score 0):

Limited options except total avoidance.

Cell phones are particularly noxious. The industry is *really into* the "used car sales business model" where they want you to replace your phone 1-2 times a year while you still owe more on it than it's worth, and they fold your debt into the next phone contract.

One option is actually tablets. Quality tablets (I'm talking about one brand here) can deliver 5-7 years, and with cellular data and certain apps, can even provide voice/txt.

I'm not a big fan of laptops. They tend to be less powerful due to the need to hit usable battery budgets, and that shortens the number of years they can run a current OS version.  Chips are pretty much at hard physics limits on transistor density and MHz speed, so rather than create a stable computing platform, they're just forcing planned obsolescence in other ways. Remember, Moore's "Law" wasn't a physical law, it was a marketing credo of how to pace development to sell the most PCs.

The other problem with laptops is they're fragile and get broken a lot, and a physically broken laptop is e-waste - they don't generally sell case parts.   Quality tablets are much more robust when used with tough cases.  As far as desktop computing, I think using a hot-blooded short-lived laptop for that is dumb. I prefer a capable desktop from a reliable vendor; it will make it through more OS upgrades than the laptop will.34

Answer (score 0):

A few options that manufacturers can do, but won't unless forced to (there may be more).

- Modularity: Design to be repaired, and upgraded.
- No lock-in: Design to allow user to be free to do what they want.

  - Can run any OS
  - Can run any apps,
  - Can use modules from any supplier
- No built-in degradation: some products get slower over time. Sometimes this is intentional, sometimes there is just no effort to fix an accidental problem. E.g.

  - NTFS (file-system of MS-Window) suffers from fragmentation. File-system could be changed, but this behaviour benefits MS, with increased sales.
  - MS repository, a simple key-value store (the fastest database type possible), is poorly implemented and slows down. Could be fixed, but benefits MS, with increased sales.
  - Battery in phone degrades (because of poor battery thermal management), and phone has to slow down. Battery can not be replaced. Again more sales.

As can be seen, what is good for the user, and what is good for the company is misaligned.

Comment: Yes, the question implicitly revolves around what can one do when manufacturers don't do anything.